# A way to map a folder in Windows Vista to fake drive?

Tags: windows-vista

I don't have a drive F, but I need to create a virtual. So i need to:

1. Create a virtual drive F
2. Map c:\xampp\htdocs to this new drive under: F:\htdocs
3. I need to do this on Windows VISTA

Is there a way to do this? Or even a program that does this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in `subst` command is what you're looking for. See http://forums.techarena.in/tips-tweaks/1079564.htm for usage details.

Comment: Use 'subst F: C:\xampp' :)

Comment: IIRC, you can also use the Disk Management tool.